# React.JS - How to dynamically update the state of a Next.JS router component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, next-router

In my app, I have a togglable switch that is either checked or unchecked based on the dynamic URL of the app. For example, if the URL has a param called `followType` set to `following` (e.g. `https://www.example.com/home?followType=following`), I want the switch to be already checked on page load.

However, the `useRouter()` function initially gets the following type as `null` and then takes a second to get the actual value for the param. This change is not reflected in what I'm returning and only when I update the state of the page does the switch actually reflect the values in the param.

Here's a code sample below:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Switch from "react-switch";

const FollowToggle = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(router.query.followType === "following" ? true : false)
  
  const handleChange = nextChecked => {
    setChecked(nextChecked);
  };

  return (
    <Switch
      checked={checked}
      onChange={handleChange}
      ...
```

TLDR; how do I update the state of the switch that I am returning when the `router.query.followType` changes from `null` to the actual value in the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `useEffect` to listen to `router.query.followType` state update in this case.

`useEffect` can check every state update from your states automatically.

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Switch from "react-switch";

const FollowToggle = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(router.query.followType === "following")

  useEffect(() => {
    setChecked(router.query.followType === "following")
  }, [router.query.followType])
  
  const handleChange = nextChecked => {
    setChecked(nextChecked);
  };

  return (
    <Switch
      checked={checked}
      onChange={handleChange}
      ...
```